# create dense dynamic array (array of value) as library

Tags: c++, data-structures

I tried to create packed array as a data structure for a game engine as described here:-
http://experilous.com/1/blog/post/dense-dynamic-arrays-with-stable-handles-part-1
[image: diagram]

In short, the structure stores values, instead of pointers.

Here is a draft.

```
template<class T> class Id{
    int id;
}
template<class T> class PackArray{
    std::vector <int>indirection ;  //promote indirection here
    std::vector <T>data;
    //... some fields for pooling (for recycling instance of T)
    Id<T> create(){
        data.push_back(T());
        //.... update indirection ...
        return Id( .... index  , usually = indirection.size()-1 .... )
    }
    T* get(Id<T> id){   
        return &data[indirection[id.id]];
        //the return result is not stable, caller can't hold it very long
    }
    //... others function e.g. destroy(Id<T>) ...
}
```

The prototype works as I wished, but now I concern the beauty of old code.

For example, I had always created a new object like this:-

```
Bullet* bullet = new Bullet(gameEngine,velocity);
```

Now I must call :-

```
Id<Bullet> bullet = getManager()->create()->ini(velocity);
// getManager() usually return PackArray<Bullet>*
// For this data structure, 
//    if I want to hold the object for a long time, I have to cache it as Id.
```

**Here are the questions :-**

1. The new version of code is more ugly.
   Should I avoid it?    How to avoid it?
2. How to avoid / reduce programmer's-work of the above modification?
   It is very tedious, when there are many of them scattering around.

(Edit) The scariest part is change in the type declaration e.g.

```
class Rocket{
    std::vector<Bullet*> bullets;  
    //-> std::vector<Id<Bullet>> bullets;
    void somefunction(){
       Bullet* bullet = someQuery();
       //-> Id<Bullet> bullet
    }
}//These changes scatter around many places in many files.
```

This change (inserting the word "Id<>") means that the game logic has to know the underlying data structure that used to store Bullet.

If the underlying data structure would be changed again in future, I will have to manually refactor them one by one again (from Id<> to something else),  i.e. lower maintainability.

3. (optional) What is the name of this data structure / technique?
4. As a library, should Id has a field of PackArray* to enable accessing the underlying object (e.g. Bullet*), without manager()?

   Bullet* bullet = someId->getUnderlyingObject();

Comment: Regarding 2. how about `make_id<Bullet>(velocity)`? See `std::make_unique` and `std::make_shared` for reference. Use `make_id` to dispatch to the right manager according to the template parameter. 3. You might [consider using `handle`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_(computing)#Comparison_to_pointers) instead of `id`: *Typically the handle is an index [...] into a global array...*. 4. With handles you don't get to the object without the manager, with your `Handle<T>` why not provide this functionality? E.g. the handle could get its manager the same way `make_id/handle` got it.

Comment: Thanks, you totally understand the problem.    (item 3 - 4 are solved)

I have edited my question a little (item 2)  If you can, please post the full answer, so I can accept.    

I am also appreciated if you also express opinion on item 1.

Comment: Just curious; why a dense array instead of a list?

Comment: I just want to emphasize that the data are stored as value, and this structure has a unique way to reduce memory allocation by polling.  In the lowest level, it is just a list as you said.

Comment: You probably mean "pooling", not "polling". These are very different concepts.

Comment: Imagine a component that stores such a handle. Can you ensure that it will be notified when the handle is invalidated? You can't reuse ID's (slots in your `indirection` array). If you do, a stored handle could suddenly point to a different object. This makes your `indirection` array grow and fragment over time what kind of defeats the purpose of a packed data structure. Of course I don't know your exact use case. You might find weak_ptr semantics interesting.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.   I can never be sure that it is invalidated or not.  That mean I have to carefully manage it (destroy all members & unlink them before the PackArray deletion).   After prototyping a small game logic, I found that this restriction is not very hard.   You mean "weak_ptr" of what?, I am interested.

Comment: Dangling pointers are a common problem that can lead to heap corruption. You'll only encounter these bugs as your program becomes more complex. A weak pointer allows you to check if the pointed-to object is still alive. I'm proposing that you adapt this functionality for your Id<> handles because it makes object lifetime management much easier. With a trade-off of course. I'm commenting here because i recently refactored a game engine with 40k lines of code and had similar problems. Also, you can increase maintainability using typedefs: `typedef Id<Bullet> BulletRef`

Comment: Should I also cache Id<> inside PackArray, and PackArray has to help to invalidate it?   I am using Entity component system.     This link http://bitsquid.blogspot.de/2014/08/building-data-oriented-entity-system.html provide the checking functionality whether a component is still alive (for this type of data structure only).  However, its quality is for debugging purpose.   If you have any other ways / links, please inform me.     I am lacking a lot of examples (everything about game engine) and thank for the typedef!

Comment: This is getting a bit off topic. And sorry for the late answer. Interesting article! It deals with exactly the things I mentioned. Additional functionality will always add overhead (if that's what you mean by debug quality). --- I relied on `std::weak_ptr` to automatically invalidate tasks in a queue when a resource is deallocated. `weak_ptr` only works with `shared_ptr` -> I lost control over object deallocation. I ended up writing my own set of smart pointers which support weak pointers for unique pointers. This only works because I can guarantee a single-threaded environment for them.

Comment: You could also use a message queue to inform your components about object deallocation. But that's no silver bullet either. http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/event-queue.html (very nice book btw, available online for free)

Comment: @1000ml     I have read it before, but the event technique seems to be slow.  I would like to talk more, but here is an inappropriate place to chat, you can reach me personally from my profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour of `id` sounds like `handles`, as in you don't give out information about the storage method, but guarantee access as long as the handle is valid. In the later respect handles behave like raw pointers: you won't be able to tell if it's valid (at least without the manager) and the handle might be reused at some point.

The question if changing from raw pointers to handles produces uglier code is very opinionated and I'd rather keep this objective: there's a balance between readably explicit and too much typing - everyone draws their own limits here. There's also advantages to having the calling site specify `getManager`: maybe there are multiple possible instances of these managers, maybe getting the manager requires locking and for multiple operations you want to lock only once. (You can support both of these cases in addition to what I present below.)

Let's use pointer/iterator notation to access the objects through our handles, reducing the amount of code changes necessary. Using `std::make_unique` and `std::make_shared` for reference, let's define `make_handle` to dispatch the creation to the right manager. I've adjusted `PackArray::create` a bit to make the following example more compact:

```
template<class T> class Handle;
template<class T> class PackArray;
template<class T, class... Args> Handle<T> make_handle(Args&&... args);

template<class T>
struct details {
    friend class Handle<T>;
    template<class U, class... Args> friend Handle<U> make_handle(Args&&... args);
private:
    // tight control over who get's to access the underlying storage
    static PackArray<T>& getManager();
};

template<class T>
class Handle {
    friend class PackArray<T>;
    size_t id;

public:
    // accessors (via the manager)
    T& operator*();
    T* operator->() { return &*(*this); }
};

template<class T>
class PackArray {
    std::vector<size_t> idx;
    std::vector<T> data;

public:
    template<class... Args>
    Handle<T> create(Args&&... args) {
        Handle<T> handle;
        handle.id = data.size();
        idx.push_back(data.size());
        // enables non-default constructable types
        data.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return handle;
    }
    // access using the handle
    T& get(Handle<T> handle) {
        return data[idx[handle.id]];
    }
};

template<class T, class... Args>
Handle<T> make_handle(Args&&... args) {
    Handle<T> handle = details<T>::getManager().create(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return handle;
}

template<class T>
T& Handle<T>::operator*() {
    return details<T>::getManager().get(*this);
}
```

And the usage code would look like:

```
Handle<int> hIntA = make_handle<int>();
Handle<int> hIntB = make_handle<int>(13);
Handle<float> hFloatA = make_handle<float>(13.37f);
Handle<Bullet> hBulletA = make_handle<Bullet>();
// Accesses through the respective managers
*hIntA = 42; // assignment
std::cout << *hIntB; // prints 13
float foo = (*hFloatA + 12.26f) * 0.01;
applyDamage(hBulletA->GetDmgValue());
```

Every type needs a manager, i.e. if you don't define a default you'll get a compiler error. Alternatively you can provide a generic implementation (note: the initialisation of `instance` is not thread safe!):

```
template<class T>
PackArray<T>& details<T>::getManager() {
    static PackArray<T> instance;
    return instance;
}
```

You get special behaviour via template specialisation. You can even replace the manager type via template specialisation, allowing you to easily compare storage strategies (e.g. SOA vs. AOS).

```
template<>
struct details<Bullet> {
    friend class Handle<Bullet>;
    template<class U, class... Args> friend Handle<U> make_handle(Args&&... args);
private:
    static MyBulletManager& getManager() {
        static MyBulletManager instance;
        std::cout << "special bullet store" << std::endl;
        return instance;
    }
};
```

And you can even make all of this const-correct (the same techniques as implementing custom iterators apply).

You may even want to extend the `details<T>` to a full traits type... It's all a balance between generalisation and complexity.

Comment: +1  It is a perfect explanation, and far better and detailed than I expected.   I can't thank you enough for this.