# Converting "handle" to void*, how to create and store? When to delete?

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures

**Introduction**

I have created a poll data structure for a game engine, as explained in:-
http://experilous.com/1/blog/post/dense-dynamic-arrays-with-stable-handles-part-1
[image]

In short, the structure stores values, instead of pointers.

Here is a draft.

```
template<class T> class Handle{
    int id;
}
template<class T> class PackArray{
    std::vector <int>indirection ;  //promote indirection here
    std::vector <T>data;
    //... some fields for pooling (for recycling instance of T)
    Handle<T> create(){
        data.push_back(T());
        //.... update indirection ...
        return Id( .... index  , usually = indirection.size()-1 .... )
    }
    T* get(Handle<T> id){   
        return &data[indirection[id.id]];
        //the return result is not stable, caller can't hold it very long
    }
    //... others function e.g. destroy(Id<T>) ...
}
```

**Problem**

Most steps of the refactor to adopt this new data structure are simple, e.g.

```
Bullet* bullet=  new Bullet(); //old version
Handle<Bullet> bullet= packBulletArray.create(); //new version
```

The problem start when it come to some interfaces the require pointer.

As an example, one of the interfaces is the physic engine.

If I want the engine's collision callback, physic engines likes Box2D and Bullet Physics requires me to pass void*.

```
Bullet* bullet= .... ;
physicBody->setUserData(bullet); <-- It requires void*.
```

**Question:** How should I change the second line to a valid code?

```
Handle<Bullet> bullet =  .... ;
physicBody->setUserData( ???? );
```

**Caution:**

(1) There is no guarantee that this instance of "Handle" will exist in the future.

```
physicBody->setUserData( &bullet ); //can't do this   
//e.g. "Handle<Bullet> bullet" in the above code is a local variable, it will be deleted soon
```

(2) There is no guarantee that the underlying object of "bullet" will exist in the same address in the future.

```
physicBody->setUserData( bullet->get() ); //can't do this
//because "std::vector<T> data" may reallocate in the future
```

**The answer can assume that:**

(1) "physicBody" is encapsulated by me already.  It can cache generic pointers if requires, but caching a value of Handle is not allowed, because it creates a severe coupling.

(2) "bullet" has a way to access the correct "physicBody" via its encapsulator.  "physicBody" is always deleted before "bullet".

(3) "Handle" also cache "PackArray*", this cache is always a correct pointer.

I guess the solution is something about unique-pointer / make_pointer, but I don't have enough experience to use them for this problem.

P.S. I care about performance.
For reference, this is a sequel of a question [create dense dynamic array (array of value) as library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37605056/create-dense-dynamic-array-array-of-value-as-library) that has been solved.

Comment: Too hard to understand all the details. Generally the *Packed object array* should be exactly what Box2D or Bullet Physics need, a flat array of objects. When objects are added and pointers are invalidated you just update the pointers.

Comment: The real question, under all the extraneous details, appears to be a simple one about object lifetimes.

Comment: @nwp  : Do you mean PackArray's callback?  When PackArray know that the pointer is invalidated, it has to call "physicBody" to update its userData to a new void*.  I am afraid that they are quite unrelated classes, so callback might not suitable.  Furthermore, PackArray actually doesn't know when the underlying data will be reallocated, because it uses std::vector.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf : I agree.    The question can be looked from another way -   1. How/where to store the data of the void*?   2. What should be the data that void* point to?  They are both surrounded by the object lifetime problem, and this object is the one that void* point to.